# django - extracting html from a template within a view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a simple index view, but I'd like to be able to manipulate the HTML from the template before rendering it, so I'll need to extract the HTML from the template object as a string, then be able to put it back in the object when I'm done. How can I do this?

```
def index(request):
    latest_course_list = Course.objects.order_by('-start_date')
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    ctx = {
        'latest_course_list': latest_course_list,
    }
    return render_to_response('index.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: To inline things like CSS and JS before rending.

Comment: So why would you want to do that by "manipulating the HTML" rather than doing it as part of the template rendering process by using, say, a template tag?

Comment: Ah, you are of course right. That's a much better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a similar thing using:

```
render_to_string('template_name', context)
```